# Error while reading ShaDa file

Tags: neovim, shada

I get the following error even though I have a `.viminfo` in my home directory. Isn't that what it is complaining about?

```
E576: Error while reading ShaDa file: last entry specified that it occupies 11 bytes, but file ended earlier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `shada` file is corrupted.

The file should be located into: `~\nvim-data\shada\main.shada` (or in: `~/.config/nvim-data/shada/main.shada` for Unix like systems)

I would propose to:

- Stop Neovim
- Delete the `shada` file
- Restart Neovim

Comment: There is no nvim-data or main.shada in my home dir. Manjaro Os nvim 0.9.2

Comment: @lizhe On Unix like OS the path is slightly different. I have adapted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The command `:wshada!` will forcefully overwrite the shada file, which should fix this issue. Note that this will overwrite data that neovim persists between restarts such as command line history. See `:h shada-file` for more information on what exactly.

Comment: This fixed it for me, I tried deleting the SHared DAta file but that didin't solve the issues.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!